# When I run my code, I keep getting an error saying perhaps I forgot a comma. Where would this be an issue within the code?

Tags: python, list, syntax

```py
n= int(input())

a= list(range(1,"x",n+1)
print(a)

b=1:
    for b in a
        if num % 2 != 0:
           b= b*num
print(b)
```

This is for my into to python class and this is the question for context.

"Taking an integer value n from the user with input(). Your program will calculate the
product of all odd numbers from 1 through the given n. For example: the user gave
n=20. You python code will calculate the following value:
1 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 9 x 11 x 13 x 15 x 17 x 19
Your program will print out 654729075.0 back to the user.
Please calculate the value for n=23 using your program?"

When I run my code, I keep getting an error saying perhaps I forgot a comma. Where would this be an issue within the code? The r in range keeps getting highlighted.

Comment: The code did not format properly,   here is the property formatted code                                               n= int(input())

a= list(range(1,"x",n+1)
print(a)

b=1:
    for b in a
        if num % 2 != 0:
        `   b= b*num
print(b)

Comment: You can't fix code formatting in a comment.  Just edit your post and put "```" before and after your code block.

Comment: Remove the `list(` from your second line.  The error is that you forgot the `)`, but you don't need to turn this range into a list anyway.

Comment: There are several issues here. First, you're missing a second `)` on the second line of code. `range(1,"x",n+1)` is not valid python code. `range()` takes between 1 and 3 arguments, all of them numeric, so you can't pass it "x". I *think* you're doing that because the problem asks about multiplication, but the character to multiply in python is `*`, and you do not put it inside of quotes. The line `b=1:` will throw an error because it should not end in a `:`. And the line `for b in a` is missing a `:` at the end that is required. You also need to unindent all of the lines in the `for` loop.

Comment: Also the for loop doesnt have `:` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed a few issues here. First, you don’t need `list()` in your definition of a. You also don’t need a var named a at all.

Also, the syntax for `range` is `range(start, stop, step)`. You want to start at 1, stop at n+1 (because `range` is exclusive), and move forward 2 each time. Therefore, it’s `range(1, n+1, 2)`. The code will look like this:

```
n = int(input())

b = 1
for num in range(1, n+1, 2):
    b *= num

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: You are adding unnecessary "x" in code range should (start, end, [Step])

```
n= int(input())
a= list( range(1,n+1) )
print(a)
ans=1
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] % 2 != 0: 
        ans*=a[i]
    else:
        continue
print(float(ans)
```

Read:
Try to go through built in functions
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Range- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

List - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list

Answer (score 0):

The code has several flaws. The expert comments are already indicating that. here is one possible version of executable code that can do what you want.

```
n= int(input())

a=list(range(1,n+1,2))
print(a)
b = 1
for num in a:
    b *= num
print(b)
```